# How can I share a project without breaking the rules?

Tags: support, self-promotion

I had a problem that I failed to find possible solutions for on the Internet that satisfies all my requirements, so I decided to write a new package.

I see this is a problem which has considerable interest on Stack Overflow. I guess, some users could be interested in my project, but posting an answer to share the project I wrote could be considered self-promotion (which is against Stack Overflow rules).

How could I let interested people know about a new solution which may help solving their problem without breaking Stack Overflow rules?

Comment: By finding relevant questions, and writing specific, complete answers for how your library solves their problems; include code blocks using your library to solve exactly the problem in the question. Don't just write "my library can help you solve these things". Don't ever duplicate your answers, either.

Comment: Look up how Howard Hinnant answers questions about or with the C++ time and date utilities he originated. Should make a for a safe model to follow.

Comment: Simply put; write the answers as you'd write any other good answer. All the same applies, except that you must disclaim your affiliation. Also expect extra attention at these answers of yours. Some people may notice it, and go through your account to check it for spam. That's not gonna be a problem if you follow all the rules and guidelines, which I think are linked to in the questions you linked.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with avoiding coming off as self-promoting in the question that asks how to avoid coming off as self-promoting. The specifics of your problem, as well as the name (and a link) to the package you developed are immaterial to the question at hand.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship *disclose* affiliation. To "disclaim" affiliation would be to say there is no affiliation.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend re-reading https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/self-promotion/info as it seem to have all information you ever needed for this question... If not - [edit] the post to clarify.

Comment: @khelwood That is what I meant. My eyes are tired, and my brain is sleepy. ;) Thanks.

Comment: Also note that "finding relevant questions" *doesn't* mean find a random post that's in the same ballpark when the question is not asking an open ended question about "how to" do something. If the question is a debugging question, then that's *not* something on which to post an answer about your package being an alternate solution. If the question is explicitly asking "how to" do something using some other package, that's also not something to post on. If the question is asking "how to" without restrictions which preclude your package, then that could be something you post an answer on.

Comment: Don't do a lot of them, particularly as a percentage of all your contributions or your contributions around a particular time, as that can be considered over-promotion.

Comment: Ask a question with an MRE, allowing you to submit an MRE solution. If you have to provide an entire repository of code to answer the question you likely have not identified a MRE to the problem.

Comment: One of the problems which you have is that you're approaching this as "how can I promote my project" and promotion is often considered spam. It's one thing to organically see a newly asked question which you can easily answer the actual question asked by using the project you recently completed (and you disclose that it's your project). It's quite another issue to go looking for questions on which to post answers about your project (in order to promote it). The first is just using the site. The second is promotion/spam, for which there's a very low tolerance and people *will* notice.

Comment: *"How could I let interested people know about a new solution which may help solving their problem"* - put it on github and write a proper readme that search engines can index? The same way people find Stack Overflow answers, they can also find your github. IF you write a proper readme that pulls them in.

Answer (score 12):

> How could I let interested people know about a new solution which may help solving their problem without breaking Stack Overflow rules?

Frame challenge: why should you be allowed to discuss the "new solution" on Stack Overflow?

That is not rhetorical; it *is* allowed in some cases. Specifically, *if* you can write an *answer* to a properly asked *question*, that incidentally uses the package to implement the code solution in the answer, and actually *answers* the question (i.e., doesn't just use the question as a prompt to discuss the topic covered by your library - after all, this is **not a discussion forum**).

If your package has value as an actual installable package, then *chances are it does a few conceptually distinct things*. That means, it **will not work to just write an answer that says to download and use the package** (and here is a link to the documentation). Why? Because *any question that could actually be answered that way, would be unsuitable for Stack Overflow* - it should be closed as Needs More Focus.

If you are lucky enough to create something that becomes popular on its own - popular enough that people just decide to come to Stack Overflow to ask questions about using it - then you can certainly answer those questions. For example, Kenneth Reitz would be welcome to answer questions [tagged `python-requests`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-requests), as the original author of the Requests library for Python, although I believe authors are expected to disclose their affiliation.

Possibly more relevant: there is a somewhat well-known third-party Python library `more-itertools` which can be used to solve (among other things) a lot of combinatorics problems. Although [very few questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/more-itertools) are explicitly tagged with the library, people are welcome to answer other Python questions with solutions that use `more-itertools`, even if OP didn't ask about using it - as long as they're solid answers to valid questions, where using the library makes sense. Erik Rose would be welcome to do so as well, to my understanding.

Even if you disclose your affiliation, **please don't artificially create questions with the intent of promoting the library via the answer**. If a suitable question hasn't already been asked, this is a sign that the task solved by your library is not as common as you'd like to think. The underlying point here is that it seems like you are trying to draw a distinction between "share" or "let people know about", vs. "promote"; we don't see such a distinction. Write about your library in order to **answer questions**.

Comment: Note: if the question is already about the package the author / contributor does not necessarily need to disclose affiliation. It is only required when the question wasn't already about the package / library.

Comment: I don't want to create new questions... I was thinking about answering to some questions which my package is actually a possible answer

Comment: Just FYI: Disclosure of affiliation is not required when the on-topic question, which is *explicitly asking about* the thing to which the answerer is affiliated, is organically asked by a non-affiliated person and the affiliated answerer links only to official resources (e.g. official documentation, examples, etc.; i.e. *not* to marketing/general pages) and the answer *actually answers the question asked*. While disclosure is suggested/recommended, as it can improve how people receive the answer, it's not required.

Comment: @DanieleRicci - Be prepared to provide the necessary information in the answer to use your library, provide a MRE example that solves the question that was asked, and not simply a signpost directing the author (and others) to your project. Regardless if the question is about the library or the library is simply a potential solution, as the author of the library, you should disclose your affiliation with the project.